# Child Update Panel calls prerender on parent update panel in nested scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asynchronous, updatepanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="udp_RemitEditor" UpdateMode="conditional" OnPreRender="LoadParameters">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="div_RemitEditor" style="width:225px; display: none;">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnl_RemitEditor" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <Button>
                    <Content>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_ReloadEditor" style="display: none;" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Ok I have a nested update panel setup.  I have a prerender method that fills the information in the Content in the child update panel initially.  I have a Button that updates the child content asyncronously.  For some reason after that update to the child, the parent's prerender method is called again and it changes the information that the button updated back to the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the parent updatepanel, set childrenastriggers='false'...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="udp_RemitEditor" 
  UpdateMode="conditional" OnPreRender="LoadParameters" 
  ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
```